# how to get max number from a file with Linux bash shell scripts

Tags: bash, file, shell, numbers, max

How to get the maximum "rate" and the corresponding "log2c" value from a file as follows?
e.g: the max rate is 89.5039 , and log2c 3.0 . thanks a lot.

```
log2c=5.0 rate=88.7619
log2c=-1.0 rate=86.5412
log2c=11.0 rate=86.1482
log2c=3.0 rate=89.5039
log2c=-3.0 rate=85.5614
log2c=9.0 rate=81.4302
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not doing this in Awk? This should be trivial after just a brief introductory tutorial.

Comment: devnull's solution perfectly work in bash. However, my inputfile name is from a varable $filename. So, i put these words into echo " ... " | sh. forgive me , i am a newbie .

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `sort`:

```
sort -t= -nr -k3 inputfile | head -1
```

For the given input, it'd return:

```
log2c=3.0 rate=89.5039
```

If you want to read the values into variables, you can use the builtin `read`:

```
$ IFS=$' =' read -a var <<< $(sort -t= -nr -k3 inputfile | head -1)
$ echo ${var[1]}
3.0
$ echo ${var[3]}
89.5039
```

Comment: Or `IFS=$' =' read unused log2c unused rate <<< "$(sort -t= -nr -k3 inputfile | head -1)"`

Comment: @anishsane It's also no longer necessary to use head when you're going to read one line with read.

Comment: oh yes, that's right... I did not bother to change contents of `$(...)`

Comment: Thanks. The following works: filename="${prefix}.txt"      
IFS=$' =' read -a var <<< $(sort -t= -nr -k5 $filename | head -1)   
c=${var[1]}   
g=${var[3]}   
maxrate=${var[5]}    
echo "c=$c"   
echo "g=$g"   
echo "maxrate=$maxrate"

Answer (score 8):

For very large files, using `sort` will be quite slow.  In this case, it's better to use something like awk, which needs only one pass:

```
$ awk -F= 'BEGIN { max = -inf } { if ($3 > max) { max = $3; line = $0 } } END { print line }' test.txt
log2c=3.0 rate=89.5039
```

The time complexity of this operation is linear, while the space complexity is constant (and small).  Explanation:

1. `awk -F= '...' test.txt`: Invoke awk on test.txt, using `=` as the field separator
2. `BEGIN { max = -inf }`: Initialise `max` to something that will always be smaller than whatever you're reading.
3. `{ if ($3 > max) { max = $3; line = $0; } }`: For each input line, if `max` is less than the value of the third field (`$3`), then update it and remember the value of the current line (`$0`)
4. `END { print line }`: Finally, print the line we remembered while reading the input.

Comment: It didn't work on my linux nor max with gawk 4.1.4, unless you replace "print line" with "print $line"